# Why axios.get gets null while the URL works fine when visited in browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/posts/';

class PostService {
    static getPosts() {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const res = axios.get(URL);
                const data = res.data;
                resolve(
                    data.map(post => ({
                        ...post,
                        createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt)
                    }))
                )
            }
            catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

When running, the error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" occurs.
It turns out the variable `data` is null.
However, when I access the URL in brower, the data is display perfectly as below:
[screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF6p0.png)

Could someone tell me why?
Thx~

Comment: Im not sure, but you should wait for `axios.get` to get resolved with `async axios.get`. Perhaps you must prefix `getPosts` with `await getPosts`. otherwise the code looks good, more to read: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: To Marc: You are right, that is where went wrong. I should have waited for axios.get. Thank you~ But I cannot prefix ```getPosts``` with ```await```, it is a syntax error... Maybe Abraham Labkovsky's way is the only way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not waiting for the .get function call to resolve before referencing it.
In an async function you could await it but in a promise you must put asynchronous tasks in a .then()

edit: perhaps this wasn't clear,

try:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/posts/';

class PostService {
static getPosts() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(URL)
        .then(res => resolve(res.data.map(post => ({
                    ...post,
                    createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt)
                }))))
        .catch(reject)
    });
}
```